# How to create a video banner with multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, banner

I would like to create a video banner similar to what is found on this website: http://www.jespergadeberg.com/

The banner has 4 columns which displays and play a specific video depending on the column the cursor is hovering over.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise it but basically i will suggest it:

```js
$('#block1').mouseenter(function(){
 $('#video1').addClass('is-hover');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tibuakaw/pse1jjsa/